# 6 letters probability?

Tags: probability

On the planet Noux, the alphabet has only 6 letters, and every word in the Nouxian language has no more than 4 letters in it. How many words are possible? (A word can use a letter more than once, but 0 letters does not count as a word) The answer is 1554.
What I did is using the permutation with repeat formula.  n^r
n=6 letters and r=4 letters in a word
6^4=1296 but I didn't the right answer. Please help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about the 3-letter words etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You told us about the maximum number of digits which is $4$

and following Lord Shark The Unknown's comment ,there are words of $1,2,3,4$ letters

Number of words in one letter $=6^1=6$

Number of words in two letters $=6^2=36$

Number of words in three letters $=6^3=216$

Number of words in four letters $=6^4=1296$

Total words $=6+36+216+1296=1554$

I think this solves the problem.....